# The push method is not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I was just messing around and practicing my codes but array push method isn't working. It's output is just [1], every time I run it. Here is my code:

```
    var output = [];
    var count = 1

    function fizzBuzz () {
    output.push (count); 
    count ++;
    console.log (output);
    }

    fizzBuzz ();
```

Comment: the output comes as just [1] every time I run the code

Comment: http://prntscr.com/13kplt2
As you can see here count was pushed to output. Currently it is [1]

Comment: `[1]` is the expected output if you run all the code posted. You need to call `fizzBuzz ` more than once after setting `output` to `[]` to get anything else.

Comment: Is this not expected behaviour? You only pushed one value to the array, and you didn't change the array, just the count variable

Comment: I was expecting the push method to add +1 to the array every time I run the code, so that if I run it 5 times the output is something like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: Thank You, @traktor and everyone else, I got my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

.push() method is working as intended, you are only calling fizzBuzz() once, hence the [1] result.

In order to push an increment of count into output you can use a loop clause

```js
    var output = [];
    var count = 1

    function fizzBuzz () {
    output.push (count);
    count ++;
    
    }

    while(count < 10){
     fizzBuzz()
    }
    console.log (output);
```